# CodeIgnighter array information

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

from print_r

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 2729
        [title] =>
        [image_file] => M6_Black_Back.jpg
        [product] => 2
        [active] => 0
        [created] => 2013-06-19 23:14:51
        [rank] => 1
        [publish] => 0
        [back_photo] => M6_Black_Back.jpg
    )
)
```

this is in my controller

```
$data['back'] = $this->global_model->custom_query('
        SELECT *,image_file AS back_photo FROM system_product_photos
        WHERE product = 2 AND rank = 1
        ');

$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

I can't for the life of me get `<?=$back->back_photo?>` to output anything. 
Warning codeignighter rookie alert!

Comment: Try `$back['back'][0]->back_photo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$back`, in your view, is an array. You're going to need to access the specific item by index `<?=$back[0]->back_photo?>`, or change the signature of custom_query to only return one item.

Comment: +1, but I just noticed, he loads `$data` in the template, so shouldn't it be `$back['back'][0]->back_photo`?